# Changing the font based on language

Tags: css, fonts, internationalization

Is there's a way to change the font based on language in CSS?
I mean if there's an Arabic content, the font would be Droid Arabic Kufi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can. Just mark your content with the appropriate langauge code:

```
<p lang="es">Buen día, que es español.</p>
```

if you use the following CSS, the spanish text is formatted with the most-loved font style comic sans ms:

```
p[lang=es]
{
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS";
}
```

Easy!

[See this simple jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yadavidoqiye/1/)

Comment: Is there is a way without marking the language in HTML?

Comment: How should the browser know what language you use? If you don't want to use HTML/CSS than you could use JavaScript to check, if they are any arabic characters.